# Dropwizard Json pretty print query param

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I know how to pretty print the JSONby default, but I want to give the choice up to the user. Thats why I want to make it configureable via QueryParam.

This should pretty print json (if not given default is false):

```
...test123/res123?pretty=T
...test123/res123?pretty=True
...test123/res123?pretty=t
...test123/res123?pretty=true
```

Does someone have a good idea to do this without copying the same code to thousands resources? Should I do this with a messagebody writer? Or outgoing filter?

**The solution (Thanks to Alexey Gavrilov for the hint):**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.ObjectWriterModifier;

public class IndentingModifier extends ObjectWriterModifier {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndentingModifier.class);

    public static boolean doIndent = false;

    public final Boolean _indent;

    public IndentingModifier() {
        this(null);
    }

    public IndentingModifier(
            Boolean indent) {
        _indent = indent;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectWriter modify(
            EndpointConfigBase<?> endpoint,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders,
            Object valueToWrite,
            ObjectWriter w,
            JsonGenerator g) throws IOException {
        if (_indent != null) {
            if (_indent.booleanValue()) {
                LOG.debug("Using default pretty printer, because ident is null.");
                g.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            }
        } else {
            if (doIndent) {
                LOG.debug("Using default pretty printer, because ident is true.");
                g.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            }
        }
        return w;
    }
}
```

And the Container Filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.ObjectWriterInjector;

@Provider
public class JsonPrettryPrintQueryParamContainerResponseFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonPrettryPrintQueryParamContainerResponseFilter.class);

    private static final String QUERY_PARAM_PRETTY = "pretty";
    private static final String QUERY_PARAM_T = "t";
    private static final String QUERY_PARAM_TRUE = "true";
    private static final String QUERY_PARAM_F = "f";
    private static final String QUERY_PARAM_False = "false";

    @Override
    public void filter(
            ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
            ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> queryEntry : queryParams.entrySet()) {

            if (queryEntry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(QUERY_PARAM_PRETTY)) {
                String valueOfLastQueryParamIndex = queryEntry.getValue().get(queryEntry.getValue().size() - 1);
                LOG.debug(String.format("Found queryPram '%s' with value '%s'.", queryEntry.getKey(),
                        valueOfLastQueryParamIndex));

                switch (valueOfLastQueryParamIndex.toLowerCase()) {
                case QUERY_PARAM_T:
                    ObjectWriterInjector.set(new IndentingModifier(true));
                    break;
                case QUERY_PARAM_TRUE:
                    ObjectWriterInjector.set(new IndentingModifier(true));
                    break;
                case QUERY_PARAM_F:
                    ObjectWriterInjector.set(new IndentingModifier(false));
                    break;
                case QUERY_PARAM_False:
                    ObjectWriterInjector.set(new IndentingModifier(false));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In extended application class run():

```
environment.jersey().register(JsonPrettryPrintQueryParamContainerResponseFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ObjectWriterInjector and ObjectWriterModifier](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/pull/32) to customize the object writer in the resource method depending on the query parameter.

Take a look at [this code sample](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/d56af1bb3d38a9448d5dccfa6ecd23887a46b426/json/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/dw/WriteModificationsTestBase.java#L49) from the Jackson JAX-RS provider repository.

Comment: I would prefer to use a general feature, what does not appear in any ressources and just at service start, e.g. in run(). Thats why I asked if messagebody writer is a good idea. There I just have to inject the query param.

Comment: I think doing this in the filter is a better idea. There you have access to the query params and can use the ObjectWriterInjector to customize the output.

Comment: Thanks container response filtering with ObjectWriterModifier worked for me. I update my solution above.